# Moving Average Calculation In Minutes

Tags: investing, technical-analysis

I know how to calculate moving averages ("mA") over an x day period, but I am curious about minutes, or is it the same?

i.e.; for a 5 day mA you'd add the close price of each of the days and divide by 5 (day1+day2+day3+day4+day5)/5

Is it the same exact thing for minutes? i.e.; for 30 minute mA, you take the last price of each minute of the last 30 minutes and divide by 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same. In any granularity you do (price_1+price_2+ +price_n)/n